# Performance problem of MERGE statement in Azure Synapse

Tags: sql, merge, azure-synapse

My DWH is deployed on Azure Synapse SQL pool.
I loaded data to DWH by script that consists of update, insert and delete (u-i-d) operations. The duration of full load to target table was 12minutes for near 50million of rows.
Recently I tried to use MERGE statement instead of u-i-d. And I found that MERGE performance much worse than u-i-d - 1hour for MERGE against 12minutes for u-i-d!

Please share your experience with MERGE statement on Azure synapse, friends!
Does MERGE really work worse in Synapse than separate update-insert-delete operations?

Answer (score 1):

As per **MS doc** on [MERGE (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), Merge statement works better for complex statements and for simple activities merging using Insert, Update and delete statement works better.

> The conditional behavior described for the MERGE statement works best when the two tables have a complex mixture of matching characteristics. For example, inserting a row if it doesn't exist, or updating a row if it matches. When simply updating one table based on the rows of another table, improve the performance and scalability with basic INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.

- I tried to repro and compare both approaches using simple statements.
- Sample tables are taken as in below image.

[image]

- Merge statement is used to merge and it took 9 seconds

```sql
MERGE Products AS  TARGET

USING UpdatedProducts AS  SOURCE

ON (TARGET.ProductID =  SOURCE.ProductID)

--When records are matched, update the records if there is any change

WHEN  MATCHED  AND  TARGET.ProductName <>  SOURCE.ProductName OR  TARGET.Rate <>  SOURCE.Rate

THEN  UPDATE  SET  TARGET.ProductName =  SOURCE.ProductName, TARGET.Rate =  SOURCE.Rate

--When no records are matched, insert the incoming records from source table to target table

WHEN  NOT  MATCHED  BY  TARGET

THEN  INSERT (ProductID, ProductName, Rate) VALUES (SOURCE.ProductID, SOURCE.ProductName, SOURCE.Rate)

--When there is a row that exists in target and same record does not exist in source then delete this record target

WHEN  NOT  MATCHED  BY  SOURCE

THEN  DELETE ;
```

[image]

- Then tried with Update, Insert and delete statement. It took nearly 0 second.
  [image]

Update, insert and delete works better for simple scenarios.